# A verb meaning "to make a color brighter or darker"

Tags: word-choice, programming

I am writing a function which takes in components of a color (as red, green, blue component values) and makes the color brighter or darker based on the fraction that the developer provides. If the fraction is less than 0, it makes the color darker, if the fraction is greater than 0 it makes the color brighter. I am struggling to find a concise, preferably single-worded name for that function.

I have looked at some words that are relevant, such as *lighten*, *darken*, *illumine*, *shade*, and *tint*, but all of these tend to imply either making the color brighter or darker, but not suggestive of the possibility of both.

I would appreciate any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Usually the description of a task is an adjective rather than a verb. See: Brightness, luminescence, contrast, etc.

Comment: Not sure there is a specific verb or name for it: http://www.color-wheel-artist.com/hue.html

Comment: Usually one verb is insufficient to describe an action and its complete opposite.

Comment: Not sure if this answers you but when I mix color these are the questions I ask my self. Do I want the color to be Lighter or Darker? Warmer or Cooler? Brighter or Duller? Hope this answers you!
Taranehj@gmail.com

Comment: Nope. Sadly, it does not answer the question.

Comment: "Brighter" and "darker" are not opposites.

Answer (score 2):

Why not keep it simple? These are both two words, but it's concise and semantic:

`function adjustHue(fraction) {}` - This suggestion describes a change in the color itself, which is more technically correct but perhaps less semantic than the alternative, *luminance*. It is more technically correct because adjusting *luminance* of an RGB color requires changing the color's RGB value, which is, by definition, changing the color's *hue*.

`function adjustLuminance(fraction) {}` - This suggestion isn't technically accurate but might be more semantic because luminance describes the *perceived* brightness of a color. You can determine a RGB color's luminance by applying a formula to the RGB values. See this question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color. Note, though, that in order to change luminance for an RGB color, you must change hue.

Comment: they don't want to adjust the hue. if anything, they want to adjust the color's *value*.

Comment: Except that making a color darker is not Hue. Hue is the color.  Luminance is what makes a particular hue darker or lighter.

Comment: But I  do think that you're right with *adjust*

Comment: It's not possible to change the "brightness" of a color using hex RGB. Any change to the numeric hex value renders a change in hue, even if the new color looks like a brighter or darker shade of the old color. Unfortunately the word for brightness, if the asker wants to use it (though it's not technically correct in this context) is rather long, being _luminance_. You accomplish a change in _luminance_, however, by adjusting _hue_. See this question for help deriving the luminance of a given RGB value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color

Comment: Expanded my answer to somewhat explain the difference between luminance and hue.

Comment: You need to use HSV/HSB for this.

Comment: As @tchrist says, "luminance" is not what you are manipulating (at least not directly): "Perceived luminance is a notoriously difficult aspect of color to represent in a digital format (...), and this has given rise to two systems attempting to solve this issue. (...)" ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)). `adjustBrightness`, `adjustValue` or `adjustIntensity` (depending what model you are using) would be correct.

Comment: "in order to change luminance... you must change hue" is not true, unless you are referring to the margin of error by which different models are incompatible. Otherwise, whichever model you opt for, as long as it includes a representation of luminance (HSV, HSI, HSB), you can change the luminance-like attribute only, without a change in hue (as defined by that model). Thus, e.g. start with RGB, convert to HSV, change V without changing H or S, convert back to RGB, and you have not changed the hue. (Still upvoted for `adjustXXX`, that's exactly what I would have suggested.)

Comment: I don't think there's a simple answer to the question as asked, but in the same position I'd cut the gordian knot, and just call the function brighten(). It makes perfect sense that a negative parameter value would lead to  'unbrightening' it. This is standard coding practice... compare the DateAdd method in various languages, which subtracts when the parameter is negative.

Answer (score 2):

In photography, the term **exposure** is used to talk about the "light intensity" on photo objects. A photographer may "**change or alter exposure**" to adjust the light intensity, so they can get brighter or darker images/colors.

Why not borrow it?

[Please check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_(photography))

Comment: there's already a better contextual word for this - *luminance*. but neither *luminance* nor *exposure* provide what the asker wants.